# How to ensure Correct Use of alt and title Attributes in WordPress by Amateurs?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

In my project, I've encountered a recurring issue where less experienced users/clients incorrectly apply the title attribute when adding banner ads/images within WordPress using various page builders and or the media page. Often, the title attribute is misplaced or duplicated, which complicates what should be a straightforward process.

Any advice on effective strategies or existing WordPress mechanisms that can guide amateur users to correctly use alt and title attributes when inserting images or banners? The goal is to facilitate the addition of images with proper linking, and accurately placed alt and title attributes, either through a page builder interface or shortcodes.

Has anyone successfully tackled similar challenges or can share insights into guiding less tech-savvy users in maintaining web standards and best practices in content creation? What tools or custom solutions have you implemented to mitigate these types of errors?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See also [ask] and the [tour]

Comment: @ADyson Sorry about that! I rephrased.

Comment: Ok thanks, but unfortunately "best practices" is entirely subjective and scenario-specific, and thus also off-topic. We also don't do broad-based discussions or suggestions. We answer specific, focused programming questions about issues or difficulties in writing a particular piece of program code. The post also now sounds more like perhaps a UI design question than anything programming-specific, but it lacks specifics so I can't be sure.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, so what do you suggest I do? Where can I post this?

Comment: You could try in the newly-created [Discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions) area of Stackoverflow, where more subjectivity is permitted. Check the [Discussions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines) first, of course. Or no doubt there are other sites and forums online which might accept such questions. Recommending any such sites would though, of course, be off-topic :-)

Comment: @ADyson Hahah, makes sense. All right will do. Cheers

Comment: @daniel although this question is off-topic here, I highly recommend just training your client. You can give them short videos on how to correctly enter content. Beyond that, you're at the whims of their content entry. Good luck!

Comment: @disinfor I would, but we have 5 - 10 implementations daily with new partners. It costs us a lot of time every day. But thanks a lot. I'll keep looking